# Proof Problems on Proportion

Tags: proof-verification, ratio

If $ a/b=b/c $ then prove that
$a^2b^2c^2[1/a^3 + 1/(b^3+c^3)]=a^3+b^3+c^3$

I tried  by assuming $a/b=b/c=k$ but disld not get LHS=RHS

Comment: I think you should have $\frac1{b^3}+\frac1{c^3}$ instead of $\frac1{b^3+c^3}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have $$a^2b^2c^2(1/a^2+1/b^2+1/c^2)-(a^3+b^3+c^3)=-{\frac { \left( {a}^{2}-bc \right)  \left( ab-{c}^{2} \right) 
 \left( ac-{b}^{2} \right) }{abc}}
$$